# Using .htaccess and mod_rewrite to not require file extensions in php pages

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Hopefully a quick URL rewrite question for you all.

I've got a page on my site: http://www.sample.com/whatever.php

and i'd like to be able to navigate the site without typing `.php`

so http://www.sample.com/whatever would show the same thing.

I'd like this to work for any file in the root directory, so users could use the extension or not.

Any thoughts?

Comment: look up mod-rewrites on google. SO is **not** your own personal human google...

Comment: Enabling `MultiViews` would also work.

Comment: @Neal I've done some googling on it already (which is why i'm turning to SO, after). I've found a ton of examples used to hide the extension, or convert it from one to another, but i couldn't find anything explaining what I'm after....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As suggested in the comments above, I solved this issue using Apache's MultiViews

Adding the following to my .htaccess file did the trick:

```
Options +MultiViews
AddType application/x-httpd-php .php
```

**Update:** More details here:
http://www.bmt-online.org/geekisms/php-multiviews

Comment: Take care that it's a slight performance penalty in comparison to the exact RewriteRule. You should preferrably disable it in subdirectories again, if not needed.

Comment: Good to know, thanks for the tip Mario, i'll do that. It's a fairly small, low-traffic site, so i'm not overly concerned about a minor performance hit.

Answer (score 0):

I'd say this should do it

htcaccess:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule whatever$ whatever.php
```

Comment: how would this effect accessing pdf files, and other non-php files in the root folder?